# Regex .NET question

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible using Regex.Replace to match a string, but only replace a portion of that matched string?  Some way to mark part of the string that should be replaced with the replacement text parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use groups to insert parts of the original string, or you can use lookbehind and lookahead.

## Examples

Using Groups:

```
someString = Regex.Replace(someString, @"(before)content(after)", "$1new content$2");
```

Using lookaround:

```
someString = Regex.Replace(someString, @"(?<=before)content(?=after)", @"new content");
```

Comment: Looking forward to the examples :)

Comment: Works but instead of \1 you need $1

Comment: @SLaks: Why do you have the ?<= and the ?=, without them everything works perfect.  With them it doesn't work.

Comment: @Winforms: Those are lookaround assertions.  It works for me: `Regex.Replace("abc", @"(?<=a)b(?=c)", "q")`  prints `aqc`.